# what is a singleton class? Is it used in c#, if yes then where and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop

The singleton class concept is maddening me. What actually is the singleton class, and why is it used? Is there any case in which the it's necessary to use a singleton class? I actually don't know much about singleton classes, just that "it's a class which's object initialize only once ". static and readOnly... blaw blaw... what  actually is the concept of a singleton class? I see this code everywhere whenever i research on singleton class.

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Singleton();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    //instance methods
}
```

Please help me understand the singleton class or singleton concept in OOP. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for singletons are evil, that will give you insights when not to use them (and maybe you can figure out when to use them). Its taste i guess.

Comment: Note that your example code is bad: There's a race condition which might allow multiple instances of the "singleton" to be created when used in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideas of the singleton pattern is that only one instance exists.

An example of use would be where you have a license to use a remote service, but only with a limited number of queries in progress at any one time.  The client of the singleton can make requests freely without worrying about the license implications of excessive calls to the server, and the singleton manages placing the actions in a queue and making sure the license terms are met.  And because there can only ever be one singleton, you are sure to never break the license terms.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. 
This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

Example: If you class has an int index. Check out the value of index in obj3

```
        NonSingleton obj1 = new NonSingleton();//obj1.index = 0
        NonSingleton obj2 = new NonSingleton();//obj2.index = 0
        obj2.index = 11;
        NonSingleton obj3 = new NonSingleton();//obj3.index = 0


        Singleton obj1 = Singleton.Instance;//obj1.index = 0
        Singleton obj2 = Singleton.Instance;//obj2.index = 0
        obj2.index = 11;
        Singleton obj3 = Singleton.Instance;//obj3.index = 11
```

Also, A singleton allows access to a single created instance - that instance
(or rather, a reference to that instance) can be passed as a parameter
to other methods, and treated as a normal object.

A static class allows only static methods.

Comment: is there any difference between the static and singleton class object? is both are use as globaly created object?

Comment: @NomiAli: updated my answer, plz refer